# Android: how to close drawer with onBackPressed while drawer is locked

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, onbackpressed

I have a pretty standard DrawerLayout in my app. In this particular app I need the drawer to only open with an icon click, not swiping, so the drawer lock mode is set to LOCKED_CLOSED unless the user presses the proper icon.

To close the drawer I want the user to be able to use the drawer icon, the home icon on the action bar OR the native Back button. The first two work just fine, but the back button really doesn't. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be calling the set lock mode methods on a drawer layout object instead of the drawer?

Comment: Is the `GravityCompat.END` correct? Shouldn't it be `GravityCompat.START`?

Comment: It's correct. It's not a navigation drawer, so the guidelines say it should probably be on the right side.